# asp.net mvc 4.5.1 set field default based on another field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form which includes 2 fields....`Owner_ID` and `AQ_Manager`. I want to make the `AQ_Manager` field default to a name, depending on what is entered into the `Owner_ID` field. For example, if user inputs "Company A" into the `Owner_ID` field, I want to default the `AQ_Manager` field to "John Smith". Is there a way for me to accomplish this?

Model Info:

```
[DisplayName("Owner ID")]
public string Owner_ID { get; set; }
[DisplayName("AQ Manager")]
public string AQ_Manager { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner_ID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required CreateEditFieldNamesSpan" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Owner_ID (SelectList)ViewBag.VBProjectOwnerList, "--Select Owner--")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner_ID)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AQ_Manager, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 CreateEditFieldNamesSpan" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AQ_Manager)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AQ_Manager)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways. What have you tried?

Comment: I've search other threads, but don't see anything exactly like my scenario. I don't know how to code this. I assume I would have a function that is called when the Owner_ID field is changed, that looks at what is entered and then has a case to assign a name to manager based on the owner collected.

Comment: You could for example handle the `.change()` event of the first textbox and post its value to a controller method that returns json containing the text for the 2nd textbox and update its value. But without knowing more about what your doing its impossible to give you the correct solution. If you only had a few choices for example, you could just store the options for the 2nd textbox in a javascipt array and get then from there to avoid calling the server.

Comment: Thank you. There are only 3 choices...if Owner ID is "abc" then make AQ_Manager "John", if Owner ID is "def" then make manager "Bob", if Owner_Id is "ghi", make manager "Jim". This form brings in a project record that has already been added elsewhere. When the project closes, the record is edited and a close date added. At this point, the AQ_Manager should be auto-assigned based on the Owner company. I added the model and view above.

Comment: Your view shows that `Owner_ID` is not editable (you have just used `@Html.DisplayFor()`, not `EditorFor()`. Is that just a typo? And if here are only 3 choices for `Owner_ID`, shouldn't it be a dropdownlist?

Comment: Yes, it is a drop-down...sorry, I copied the wrong field. There are many fields in this view with similar names (I am changing the name here). We have several situations in the application where we will want to do this same thing (set a value based on another field), so this is just an example of one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you have indicated that there are only 3 options for `Owner_ID`, so you could add a property to your view model to store the associated defaults (say) `public List<string> DefaultManagers { get; set; }` and in the GET method, initialize the collection and add the 3 values (in the same order as the 3 options)

```
model.DefaultManagers = new List<string>{ "John", "Bob", "Jim" };
return View(model);
```

and in the view, include the following script

```
var defaults = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DefaultManagers))
```

which will create a javascript array containing the 3 values. Then handle the `.change()` event of your dropdownlist an update the textbox

```
$('#Owner_ID').change(function() {
  var index = $(this).children('option:selected').index();
  $('#AQ_Manager').val(defaults[index]);
});
```

An alternative, if the view was more complex and you need to update multiple inputs, would be to use ajax to call a controller method that returns the result(s) you need

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetDefaults")';
$('#Owner_ID').change(function() {
  $.getJSON(url, { id: { $(this).val() }, function(data) {
    $('#AQ_Manager').val(data.DefaultManager);
    $(anotherElement).val(data.SomeOtherPropery);
  });
});
```

and the controller method would be

```
public JsonResult GetDefaults(string id)
{
  // get the values you need based on the selected option, for example
  var data = new { DefaultManager = "Jim", SomeOtherPropery = someOtherValue };
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Once again, you have helped me immensely! Thank you so much. I had seen a suggestion for using Ajax on another thread, but the first option here seems much more straighforward for this instance. But, we have another case where the second would work better, which I will try. I am just shaky about writing the code at this point and need direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

as per your question you are entering a value in 'Owner_Id' field. we can easily set up a default value in 'AQ_Manager' field by using java script or JQuery. The syntax changes it depends up on what type of your fields

Comment: I added the model and view info above.